# How to open a ng-bootstrap modal from the left or right side?

Tags: ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I want to make ng-bootstrap modal to take full window height and open it from left or right side as like sidebar? It mean it should be left or right aligned.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at [PrimeNG dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dialog), I want to habe the same options for the position of a modal as there (most wanted postion left and right).